# Add different number of items per row using CSS Selector

Tags: html, css

I want to add a different number of items per row in CSS.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap:
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So, I want to create the next logic:

1. on the first row to have 4 items
2. on second 3 items
3. on third 1 item

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: if you want to create 3 row, create 3 parent `<div>`

Comment: @EliotAlderson, i want to do this without  creating 3 rows. Do you know a solution?

Comment: Are they always gone be like this or is the amount of children dyanmic? What are your browser requirements, like do you support ie11 and older mobile browsers?

Comment: please give the expected preview as image...!

Comment: using flex is a must requirement?

Comment: @StefanWang, no

Comment: @EliotAlderson, I ADDED AN IMAGE

Comment: How about browser support, that is the key to this?

Comment: @Dejan.S, the code should be supported by all last browsers

Comment: parent should have only 7 children? I mean if I can add some to use as line-break?

Comment: @StefanWang, could be more, but i don't want to use <br> because my items wul be generated from an js array, so i have to have the possibility to add <br> without using tags if you understand what i mean

Comment: @Asking, Then what about "nth-child" selector or "break" class ?

Comment: @StefanWang, how to add a <br> without inserting it traditionaly?

Comment: @Asking If you can use JS, why don't you add "break" elements dynamically?

Comment: @StefanWang, how to add brake with nth child?

Comment: @Asking, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64477875/8683086

Comment: @Asking, or are you going to add break with nth-child dynamically using js?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**With break elements**

---

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**With pseudo-elements and nth-child**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.parent::before, .parent::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(n + 5) {
  order: 1;
}
.child:nth-child(n + 8) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Answer**

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div> <br>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div> <br>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be done by using `:nth-child()` selector.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.child:nth-child(9), .child:nth-child(5) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Or can be done by using `line-break` class.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.line-break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```